# How to match features only in a part two given images?

Tags: opencv, matching

I have two images.
And after finding the keypoints and descriptors, I want to search for matching features for the features in image1 in only a particular part of image 2. 
Can I achieve it through matchesMask parameter of matches?
Or, is there any other method?
Please let me know.
P.s.- I am using FAST detector, ORB extractor and BFMatcher as of now.

Comment: Check if isMaskSupported() returns true for the BFMatcher. In it does, you can use a mask when calling the matching functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would copy the "particular part of image 2" in another matrix, and use it for the detection / matching.

For instance, if you wanted to create a matrix pointing to the region of "image2" defined by the first 5 columns and 10 rows, you could do:

```
cv::Mat subMatrix = image2.colRange(0, 5).rowRange(0, 10);
```

And then you would use `subMatrix` for the matching.